# How to convert a Cardano address string to the Plutus address class

Tags: plutus, cardano-address

The title says it. How can I convert an address, such as the one that the Nami wallet returns, to the `Address` data class in Plutus ?

I have searched the GitHub repository but I could only find this low level function in `Cardano.Ledger.Address`:

```
-- | Deserialise an address from the external format. This will fail if the
-- input data is not in the right format (or if there is trailing data).
deserialiseAddr :: CC.Crypto crypto => ByteString -> Maybe (Addr crypto)
```

If this is the function to use, how to convert the `Addr` class to the `Address` class ?